# How to move selected item from one default list to another defalut list

Tags: java, swing

This is code, i have so far, so i want to move selected item from one list to another, Even i don't know , like in the second list, i need to getElement or addelement...
please help me..you can just explain me, what can i do to move one element from list to another, by giving an example

```
 //this is the code, just to the set the position  
GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;  
citiesLabel.setText("Destination City");
gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridConstraints.gridy = 0;

// below code is also set the position of the list

gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
getContentPane().add(citiesLabel, gridConstraints);
citiesScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
citiesScrollPane.setViewportView(citiesList);
gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
getContentPane().add(citiesScrollPane, gridConstraints);

**This is my first list , which have all the values , that i want to move**

 final DefaultListModel citiesListModel = new DefaultListModel();
citiesListModel.addElement("San Diego");
citiesListModel.addElement("Los Angeles");
citiesListModel.addElement("Orange County");
citiesListModel.addElement("Ontario");
citiesListModel.addElement("Bakersfield");
citiesListModel.addElement("Oakland");
citiesListModel.addElement("Sacramento");
citiesListModel.addElement("San Jose");
citiesListModel.addElement("San Francisco");
citiesListModel.addElement("Eureka");
citiesListModel.addElement("Eugene");
citiesListModel.addElement("Portland");
citiesListModel.addElement("Spokane");
citiesListModel.addElement("Seattle");
citiesList.setModel(citiesListModel);
citiesList.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

// this code sets the position of the selected list

```
 SecondLabel.setText("Selected Cities");
gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridConstraints.gridy = 0;

gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
getContentPane().add(SecondLabel, gridConstraints);
SecondScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
SecondScrollPane.setViewportView(SecondList);
gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
getContentPane().add(SecondScrollPane, gridConstraints);

**This is my second list, which is empty, where i want to the moved value..**

DefaultListModel citiesListModel1 = new DefaultListModel();
citiesListModel1.addElement("aa");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
citiesListModel1.addElement("");
SecondList.setModel(citiesListModel1);
SecondList.setSelectedIndex(0);


    **This is  the button,for help me move selected city, from first list**
AssignButton.setText("Add Cities");
gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
getContentPane().add(AssignButton, gridConstraints);
AssignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your second model don't need a bunch of empty elements (unless you intend to allow the use to move items into a specific location).

In you assign action listener, you will want to check what elements are selected and then simply add the, to your second lists model.

Use [JList#getSelectedValuesList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29) to get a `List` of the selected values from the first list.  Simply interate through the list and add each element to the second list.

Depending on your needs, you can either remove the selected items from the first list or provide a check to determine if the items already exists in the second list